# Breath of the Wild DLC : Account based or Console based?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, nintendo-switch

Me and my SO have been playing Breath of the Wild each on our accounts, on the same Nintendo Switch.

If one of us buys the DLC, is it accessible by both accounts on the console or only to the account that bought it?

Comment: Is there any DLC even available yet? I know they're planning on releasing some, but I have not heard of any being released yet.

Comment: Theres DLC to buy, not released yet, but it does give you chests with bonus stuff.

Comment: I do not believe this question can be answered at this point in time as the DLC is currently unreleased content and, as far as I know, there has been no official release of information on how DLC is tied to accounts.

Comment: Some elements related to the DLC is available

Comment: Is there DLC released for *any* Switch games? Otherwise this question is both unanswerable (because there's no previous DLC to compare to) and off-topic (there's no way to know unless a dev specifically states it, since it is not released yet).

Comment: @MageXy as Fredy said, there is currently DLC for the game, it is currently purchaseable, and it currently is functional.

Comment: @Seiyria Purchaseable does not mean playable, or even downloadable. That's why I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: @MageXy as I just said... it is currently purchaseable and functional for Breath of the Wild. Did you miss that part?

Comment: "[All user accounts on your active Nintendo Switch console can play games you’ve purchased with your Nintendo Account.](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22467/~/nintendo-accounts-on-nintendo-switch-%28faq%29)" This makes me think DLC would work the same way, but I'm not 100% on it.

Comment: I can confirm that both my girlfriend and I can access the DLC that I purchased on the same switch, but with different accounts

Comment: This question should be open. There is DLC available. Currently, the [expansion pack](http://www.zelda.com/breath-of-the-wild/expansion-pass) is all that is, but it adds treasure chests to the game and a unique Nintendo Switch shirt, which in my eyes, qualifies as a DLC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [Nintendo help pages](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22317/p/897):

> While a console is active for your Nintendo Account, everyone on the console can play the games you’ve purchased.

Although this is talking about games, I can't imagine that DLC would work differently.  [One Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/5xmbtf/dlc_on_multiple_accounts/) seems to confirm that DLC works just like the games:

> ...I can confirm that the dlc works on both accounts.

Numerous articles, such as [this IGN one](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/02/17/nintendo-switch-eshop-purchases-will-be-tied-to-a-user-account) on the internet state that purchases made on the Switch are linked to the account.  But what that means is, if you were to move you account to a new console, you can download anything you've previously purchased at no cost again, something that doesn't appear to be possible on previous Nintendo platforms.

Comment: You can download at least 3DS/Wii U games again if your account is linked. I've been through probably 3 3DS systems so far, and I've always been able to restore my content afterwards.